# CUPS compilation fails on Cygwin

Tags: compiling, cygwin, cups, linker

I was brave and tried to compile CUPS in a 32-bit Cygwin environment. I used the standard sources from the tarball.

All went fine until linking.

http://pastebin.com/QSKvLSmT

Here's the end of the transcript:

```
Compiling raster.c...
raster.c:1: warning: -fPIC ignored for target (all code is position independent)
Linking libcupsimage.so.2...
../cups/libcups.a(file.o): In function `cupsFileRewind':
/opt/cups/cups-1.4.8/cups/file.c:1465: undefined reference to `_inflateEnd'
../cups/libcups.a(file.o): In function `cups_fill':
/opt/cups/cups-1.4.8/cups/file.c:2096: undefined reference to `_crc32'
/opt/cups/cups-1.4.8/cups/file.c:2098: undefined reference to `_inflateInit2_'
/opt/cups/cups-1.4.8/cups/file.c:2133: undefined reference to `_inflate'
/opt/cups/cups-1.4.8/cups/file.c:2136: undefined reference to `_crc32'
../cups/libcups.a(file.o): In function `cupsFileSeek':
/opt/cups/cups-1.4.8/cups/file.c:1569: undefined reference to `_inflateEnd'
../cups/libcups.a(file.o): In function `cups_compress':
/opt/cups/cups-1.4.8/cups/file.c:1873: undefined reference to `_crc32'
/opt/cups/cups-1.4.8/cups/file.c:1900: undefined reference to `_deflate'
../cups/libcups.a(file.o): In function `cupsFileOpenFd':
/opt/cups/cups-1.4.8/cups/file.c:996: undefined reference to `_deflateInit2_'
/opt/cups/cups-1.4.8/cups/file.c:1002: undefined reference to `_crc32'
../cups/libcups.a(file.o): In function `cupsFileClose':
/opt/cups/cups-1.4.8/cups/file.c:121: undefined reference to `_inflateEnd'
/opt/cups/cups-1.4.8/cups/file.c:150: undefined reference to `_deflate'
/opt/cups/cups-1.4.8/cups/file.c:174: undefined reference to `_deflateEnd'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:331: recipe for target `libcupsimage.so.2' failed
make[1]: *** [libcupsimage.so.2] Error 1
Makefile:34: recipe for target `all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

What to do?

Comment: There seems to be a CUPS repository in [`cygwin-ports`](http://cygwin-ports.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=cygwin-ports/cups;a=summary), have you tried this one?

Comment: Thank you so much, and why don't you make this an answer :) Will look at the port.

Comment: I wasn't sure if you used this port already... I'll add an answer `:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [CUPS port](http://cygwin-ports.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=cygwin-ports/cups;a=summary) in [`cygwin-ports`](http://cygwin-ports.sf.net), they provide version 1.4.6 as of January 30th 2011.

It [patches quite a lot](http://cygwin-ports.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=cygwin-ports/cups;a=blob_plain;f=1.4.6-cygwin.patch;hb=0880801d7719f1af7e269ccd47f05e9b6c52d517)...

Comment: I'll look into that soon, thank you so much for answering!

Comment: I was not able to install it. It depends on cups 1.4.6 which I could not find.

Comment: That should be dealt with by the cygwin ports tool, fetching and installing.

Comment: @sr_ would you happen to have an updated link ? I'd like to try the CUPS cygwin port.